# Why Buzzer interfere with PWM?

Tags: pwm, buzzer

This is the code:

```
#define TMST A2 // Thermistor
#define BZR 10  // Buzzer
#define FanP 11 // Fan

void setup() {
  DDRD = B11000000;
  DDRB = B00001111;
  DDRC = B00000000;
  TCCR2B = TCCR2B & B11111000 | B00000101; // pin 3 & 11 -> 245Hz
  T0 = 25 + 273.15;
}

void loop() {
  if (hallState > magnetDistance) {
    PORTB &= ~(1 << 0); // port manipulation -> LOW
    strcpy(WPStatus, "OFF");
    if (Alarm == 1) { // this will be set in setting menu
      if ((millis() - BZRT) > 500) {
        tone(BZR, 2300);
        BZRT = millis();
      }
      if ((millis() - BZRT) > 250) {
        noTone(BZR);
      }
    }
    else {
      noTone(BZR);
    }
  }
  else {
    PORTB |= (1 << 0); // port manipulation -> HIGH
    noTone(BZR);
    strcpy(WPStatus, " ON");
  }

  if ((millis() - fanTimer) > 2000) { // checks every 2 seconds if temperature changed
    Thermistor();
    if (TX <= 32) {
      analogWrite(FanP, 60); // Fan spinning speed
    }
    if (TX > 32 && TX <= 36) {
      analogWrite(FanP, 120);
    }
    if (TX > 36) {
      analogWrite(FanP, 255);
    }
    fanTimer = millis();
  }
}
float Thermistor() { // reading and calculating from thermistor
  VRT = analogRead(TMST);
  VRT = (5.00 / 1023.00) * VRT;
  VR = 5 - VRT;
  RT = VRT / (VR / 10000);
  ln = log(RT / 10000);
  TX = (1 / ((ln / 3977) + (1 / T0)));
  TX = TX - 273.15;
  return TX; // returning the temperature
}
```

The 5V buzzer connected to a PWM pin with a 100 ohm resistor, thermistor and fan are connected to Arduino like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQKArY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why When buzzer is alarming fan stops spinning?

Comment: I have an idea why, but from that code snippet I cannot be certain. You need to post your *whole* code, since the part that will tell me if I am right in my surmise or not is the part you have replace with the comment "// defined Variables and stuff".

Comment: @Majenko the whole code is too long, but i added the part you mentioned.

Comment: Ta. Also, which Arduino are you using for this?

Comment: @Majenko Arduino UNO

Comment: "Use of the tone() function will interfere with PWM output on pins 3 and 11." https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/

Comment: the pin for tone() doesn't need to be a pwm pin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tone()` command uses Timer2 to generate the square wave (it triggers an interrupt which toggles an IO pin).

However Timer2 is also used to generate the PWM signal on pins 3 and 11.

Thus you cannot use `tone()` and PWM on pins 3 or 11 simultaneously.

The simple fix: use PWM from pins 5, 6, 9 or 10 to control your fan.

Comment: an off topic question; since i can't use that pin anymore and other pins are occupied, is it better to use a series of diodes to reduce the fan speed or a high wattage resistor would work?

Comment: A high wattage resistor would work. That is basically what is used in mains fans with the buttons that change the speed.

Comment: you're the best.

Comment: @newbie, you can use pin 10 for fan and pin 11 or any other pin for tone()

Comment: @Juraj then i have to rework the whole PCB, i already spent almost 2 month on this project. that's enough. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you don't mind your sketch blocking while playing a tone there is [TimerFreeTone](https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-timer-free-tone/wiki/Home)

Comment: or you can change the timer used by the tone() library